# JavaScript JSON find and delete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a complex JSON file with arrays and objects containing arrays and objects down about 10 levels. I load the JSON file into Node.js. I am trying to write a function that searches the entire object including all sub objects and sub arrays and deletes any key with a specific name. This is what I have:

```
function deleteKey(object, key) {
  for(var property in object) {
    if(property==key) {
      delete object[property];
    } else {
     deleteKey(object[property], key);
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting a stack size exceeded error. Is there a better way?

Comment: Just FWIW, by the time you're processing it, it's not JSON anymore. It's objects and arrays.

Comment: I know. I guess I just said JSON to clarify I have to be able to handle anything. I don't know the depth, or any other details about the format of the object.

Comment: You should not get a stackoverflow from recursively processing normal JSON (i.e. one that is not nested thousands of levels deep).

Comment: Did you mess with the prototype objects of primitive values (or `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype`), so that you've got anything enumerable in them? That would likely cause a loop.

Comment: @Bergi True...but come to think of it, it could happen with a structure that wasn't directly parsed from JSON, or was parsed with a reviver that plays games with object identity and creates circular references.

Comment: Have tried switching the action of deletion and the recursive call? So recurssion first? If your json is ~10 levels deep, stacksize should be enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming as you would want this function to work on a JavaScript object of any depth, this would be a good situation to take advantage of recursion.

```
function deleteKey(object, key) {
  for(var property in object) {
    if(property==key) {
      delete object[property];
    } else {
      if(object[property] !== null && typeof object[property] == 'object'){
        deleteKey(object[property], key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, they're already using recursion. The OP's question is more about why they're getting a stack overflow error than the basic structure. [I would also (in fact, did also when you deleted your answer, and before I fully understood the question, doh!) restore the OP's `else`; no reason to check for the property again.]

Comment: I guess not recursing into primitives did it! Interesting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: String indices are enumerable :-/